# Retrieving top 2 bids for each item in an auction

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am having trouble combining data from multiple tables. I have tried joins and subqueries but to no avail. I basically need to combine 2 queries into one. My tables (simplified):

Stock:

```
id              int(9)      PrimaryIndex    
lot_number      int(4)
description     text     
reserve         int(9)
current_bid     int(9)
current_bidder  int(6)
```

Members:

```
member_id   int(11)         PrimaryIndex
name        varchar(255)
```

Bids:

```
id          int(9)
lot_id      int(9)
bidder_id   int(5)
max_bid     int(9) 
time_of_bid datetime
```

I'm currently using 2 separate queries which with 1000's of lots, makes it very inefficient. 1st query:

```
SELECT S.id, S.lot_number, S.description, S.reserve FROM stock S ORDER BY 
S.lot_number ASC
```

The 2nd query within a while loop then gets the bidding info:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.bidder_id, B.lot_id, B.max_bid, B.time_of_bid,
M.fname, M.lname FROM bids B, members M WHERE B.lot_id=? AND
B.bidder_id=M.member_id ORDER BY B.max_bid DESC LIMIT 2
```

Below is what i would like as output from a single query, if possible:

```
Lot No. | Reserve | Current Bid | 1st Max Bid | 1st Bidder | 2nd Max Bid | 2nd Max Bidder

1       | $100    | $120        | $150        | Steve      | $110        | John
2       | $500    | $650        | $900        | Tom        | $600        | Paul
```

I have had partial success with just getting the `MAX(B.bid)` and then its related details (`WHERE S.id=B.id`), but i cant get the top 2 bids for each lot.

Comment: Could you create a sample database on www.sqlfiddle.com and share the link here?

Comment: Hi cdaiga, ive attempted to create what you asked for here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/658272 let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign a row number `rn` to rows within each group of `lot_id` in table `bids` (highest bid gets 1, 2nd highest bid gets 2 and so on). The highest bid and second highest bid will be on two different rows after the `LEFT JOIN`.  Use `GROUP BY` to merge the two rows into one.

```
select  s.lot_number, s.reserve, s.current_bid, 
max( case when rn = 1 then b.max_bid end) as first_max_bid,
max( case when rn = 1 then m.name end) as first_bidder,
max( case when rn = 2 then b.max_bid end) as second_max_bid,
max( case when rn = 2 then m.name end ) as second_bidder
from 
stock s
left join
(select * from
  (select *,
   (@rn := if(@lot_id = lot_id, @rn+1,
              if( @lot_id := lot_id, 1, 1))) as rn
   from bids cross join
   (select @rn := 0, @lot_id := -1) param
   order by lot_id, max_bid desc
) t 
where rn <= 2) b
on s.lot_number = b.lot_id
left join members m 
on b.bidder_id = m.member_id
group by s.lot_number, s.reserve, s.current_bid
order by s.lot_number
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to get the correct data if using sqlfiddle.com/#!9/658272 , although the sample DB may be incomplete as i haven't used the site before, so may need refining a bit, thanks.

Comment: @HeadbangA your test data in the sqlfiddle is indeed incomplete.  Lots of bids without an entry in the stock table.

Comment: it may be a bit confusing but stock.id is equivalent to bids.lot_id NOT bids.id, just inconsistent naming on my part. It does seem to work with with some minor tweaking from your example. working example here : sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00cb8b/1